# ReactJS: WARNING in [eslint]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I have created a ReactJS project using the npm method. The index.html is organized as follows:
[image: web structur]
The sidebar contains links (home, tools, admin, ... etc.). Each of these links is a component, and if you click on one of them, the content section will change.
The code of the App content is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './page-structur/Navbar';
import Sidebar from './page-structur/sidebar';
import Home from './contentscomponens/home'
import administration from './contentscomponens/admin'
import PFE from './contentscomponens/pfe'
import CP from './contentscomponens/cp'
import Tools from './contentscomponens/additionaltools'

import '../../css/accueil/accueil.css'

class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className=" flex-column" id="sidebar">
            <Sidebar /> 
          </div>
                
          <div id="rest" className="flex-column">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark shadow-5-strong sticky-top container-fluid">
              <Navbar />
            </nav>
            <main id="main-content">
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/administration" component={administration} />
                <Route path="/pfe" component={PFE} />
                <Route path="/cp" component= {CP} />
                <Route path="/tools" component= {Tools} />
              </Routes>     
            </main>
          </div> 
        </BrowserRouter>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }   
}
export default App;
```

When I run the project, the terminal shows me these warnings:

[eslint]
src\js\components\App.js

Line 2:23:  'Routes' is defined but never used
no-unused-vars

Line 2:30:  'Route' is defined but never used
no-unused-vars

Line 6:8:   'Home' is defined but never used
no-unused-vars

Line 7:8:   'administration' is defined but never used
no-unused-vars

Line 8:8:   'PFE' is defined but never used
no-unused-vars

Line 9:8:   'CP' is defined but never used
no-unused-vars

Line 10:8:  'Tools' is defined but never used
no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each
warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in [eslint]
src\js\components\App.js
The Route doesn't load the components, and the content section is still empty.
Can you please help me fix the problem?

Comment: eslint is telling you you have defined some variables but never used them, so can safely simplify your codebase by removing them.  These are warnings, not errors; you can ignore them if you want to, but the messages tell you exactly what line of which files to look at if you do want to correct them.

Comment: @Daniel, I know it works, but the problem is that the components themselves are not loading. The page is still empty

Comment: That would probably have been worth mentioning as part of the question

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have the [`eslint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) module installed, however, you also need React-specific linting rules for ESLint. Make sure you have the [`eslint-plugin-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react) module installed as well.

Install it by running the following command: `npm install eslint-plugin-react --save-dev`.

Once it is installed, edit your `.eslintrc.json` file, so that it would include the following plugin:

```
'extends': [
    'plugin:react/recommended'
]
```

The ESLint warnings should disappear afterward.

Module documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react